# MOTD - show memory usage, 50-landscape-sysinfo without swap info

Tags: 14.04, swap, motd

I would like to display the MOTD without swap info, because my machine does not have swap.

I have found the link `ls /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo` which points to the file `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` which displays the following message:

```
System load:  7.5               Processes:           434
Usage of /:   84.2% of 9.72GB   Users logged in:     1
Memory usage: 5%                IP address for eth0: 10.9.8.161
Swap usage:   0%

Graph this data and manage this system at:
  https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

I have added the contents of both `ls /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo` and `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rdYqD2he#). I would like to remove `Swap usage:     0%` from this message, as it could cause confusion. I don't know what is the best way to go about doing this, any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post on http://pastebin.com/ `/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo` content and update your question with url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do so would be to disable the [`sysinfo` plugin](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/landscape-sysinfo.1.html) that handles swap usage. Unfortunately, the plugin that shows swap usage also handles the memory usage, so disabling it disabled both:

```
$ landscape-sysinfo  --exclude-sysinfo-plugins=Memory
  System load: 0.0                Users logged in:     3
  Usage of /:  56.0% of 15.62GB   IP address for eth0: 10.1.1.1
  Processes:   202

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

This can be set for the MOTD using the `/etc/landscape/client.conf` configuration file:

```
[sysinfo]
exclude_sysinfo_plugins = Memory
```

The other way would be to process the output of `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` by editing `/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo` (which is actually a symlink to a file in `/usr/lib`, so your changes may be lost when you upgrade). Something like:

```
/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo | sed 's/Swap usage: *[0-9]+%//'
```

This would also lead to ugly output if there's one more item in the list (like a second network interface).

As [Kevin points out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540775/motd-show-memory-usage-50-landscape-sysinfo-without-swap-info/541059?noredirect=1#comment740856_541059), for the specific case of no swap, the output can be tidied up and the expression simplified:

```
/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo | sed 's/Swap usage: *0% *//'
```

This should shift any entry next to Swap entry to where the Swap entry was.

Comment: Your second suggestion works for me!  I can simply use `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo | sed 's/Swap usage:   0%/                /'`. This is because my swap usage will always be 0%, and the extra blank space should fix the formatting issue.